# Cannot Save Decimal Property from UWP TextBox

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have 2 TextBoxes in UWP. They are bound to integer and decimal properties on the model entity. The integer property is saved but the decimal returns the error

```
Cannot save value from target back to source. BindingExpression: Path='ComponentDec' DataItem='Orders.Component'; target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBox' (Name='null'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String').
```

The relevant XAML is:

```
                    <ListView
                        Name="ComponentsList"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Components}">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBox Text="{Binding ComponentInt,Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
                                    <TextBox Text="{Binding ComponentDec,Mode=TwoWay,Converter={StaticResource ChangeTypeConverter}}"></TextBox>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
```

The entity class:

```
public class Component
{
    public string ComponentCode { get; set; }
    public string ComponentDescription { get; set; }
    public int ComponentInt { get; set; }
    public decimal ComponentDec { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.ComponentCode;
    }
}
```

The converter was shamelessly borrowed from Template 10:

```
public class ChangeTypeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (targetType.IsConstructedGenericType && targetType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(Nullable<>)))
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            targetType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(targetType);
        }

        if (value == null && targetType.GetTypeInfo().IsValueType)
            return Activator.CreateInstance(targetType);

        if (targetType.IsInstanceOfType(value))
            return value;

        return System.Convert.ChangeType(value, targetType);
    }
```

Why doesn't the decimal property save?

Comment: Maybe try changing "decimal" to "decimal?" as the type converter is looking for something that can be nullable

Comment: Thanks @RoguePlanetoid  but tried that and same error.

Comment: I've done a bit of debugging and found out that when it tries to save the value back the `ConvertBack` method's `Type targetType` is `System.Object` and not `System.Decimal`, but I have no idea why. What about writing a DecimalValueConverter?

Comment: Thank you @schumi1331. If you can demo a DecimalValueConverter that works I will mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work by changing `Binding ComponentDec` to `x:Bind ComponentDec`

I think this is because `x:Bind` allows `targetType` to be passed as `System.Decimal`. Whereas `Binding` passes the `targetType` as `System.Object`.

To use `Binding` I will need to write a `DecimalConverter` as @schumi1331 suggested.