# Why this UWP Binding to decimal property is not working properly?

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a decimal property called TG

```
public class Dados_Pessoa : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public decimal TG { get; set; }
    // ...
}

public class Pessoa : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Pessoa Propriedades { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

I put on the XAML:

```
<TextBox Header="TG" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Margin="145,416,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="224"
         Text="{Binding Path=Pessoa.Propriedades.TG, Mode=TwoWay}"
/>
```

When I change the TextBox value and move to other field, this error appears in Visual Studio 2017 output:

> Error: Cannot save value from target back to source.
>   BindingExpression: Path='Pessoa.Propriedades.TG'
>   DataItem='Entidades.Formularios.FormFichaCadastro'; target element is
>   'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBox' (Name='null'); target property is
>   'Text' (type 'String').

If I change the `decimal` to `double` it works fine, as expected.

I want to use `decimal` to have more precision in the numbers.

**Why is this behaviour and how to fix this?**

Comment: Looks like a issue with decimal type? https://stackoverflow.com/a/40988845/194717

Answer (score 4):

I solved it by creating a Converter for these fields that I Bind to Decimal data type.

```
public class DecimalConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {            
        Decimal.TryParse((string)value, out decimal result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Then I declared it

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:DecimalConverter x:Key="DecimalConverter" />
</Page.Resources>
```

and used :

```
<TextBox Header="TG" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Margin="145,416,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="224"
         Text="{Binding Path=Pessoa.Propriedades.TG, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource DecimalConverter}}"
         />
```

Comment: Not yet. To me it is a workaround. I will wait a little more to see if someone gives another answer.

Comment: I needed: return value.ToString();

Comment: Using ToString with numbers, also check the CultureInfo